# Initializing Negative Data Types in ARM Assembly

Tags: assembly, arm

I am currently struggling on how to set a negative/signed data type in ARM assembly via raspberry pi. I do not mean loading and storing signed integers but rather how declare a signed half word in '.data.' Once compiled I get this message:

```
Error: unknown pseudo-op: '.shalfword'
file: third.s
.section .data
a:.shalfword -2
```

Comment: Study this [Pseudo-Ops](https://sourceware.org/binutils/docs/as/Pseudo-Ops.html#Pseudo-Ops) if you are using GNU Assembler (which you didn't mention). There are no 'variables' in assembly language in the high level language sense. In any case, what you are trying to declare is a constant, not a variable, by the look of it.

Comment: Use `gcc` and see what it emits for `short a = -2;` in a file by itself (i.e. as a global variable).  The `.something` is definitely not going to have signed or unsigned in the name, just the width.

Comment: @artlessnoise: In this specific case, we want an initializer for a global (static storage), not a return value.  Read my comment again: I said to put `short a = -2;` at global scope.  Agreed if you want to go beyond that into also writing a function that loads it, that might get optimized.  (But you can make your globals `volatile`, and just having them non-`const` is probably enough)

Comment: @PeterCordes  Thanks for your edits.  I realized the global/local difference shortly after commenting.  I think that the compiler doesn't try to be 'readable' and there are 'structured assembler' pseudo-ops that let a program be more easily understood.  However, I ended up getting a godbolt example that was very close to my original example that was created without a compiler.

Answer (score 1):

Using the gnu assembler, the following should work.

```
    .text
    start:
        adr   r3,target   ; target address to r3
        ldrsh r0,[r3],#2  ; ldrsh will sign extend
        ldrsh r1,[r3]     ; .. and post increment to get the next.
        add   r0,r0,r1    ; r0 = -2 + -3
        bx    lr
    target:
       .short -2, -3
```

Here is a [godbolt example of compiler output](https://godbolt.org/z/qJdDBQ). An important point is that ARM doesn't deal with 8 or 16 bits in registers (like ah, al or ax in x86) and always uses 32 bit constants.  So immediate loads of small negative constants will be like `mvn rX,Y`.